# Is there a way to run scrapyd while running flask on Heroku

Tags: python, flask, scrapyd

I'm new to Scrapy and Scrapyd and I'm experimenting with them.

I have deployed a simple Flask app with Gunicorn that has an API endpoint that sends a call to scrapyd to schedule a spider.

Locally I have to launch scrapyd in a separate terminal to listen to calls from the Flask endpoint, but how is it possible to do the same on Heroku? I mean to be able to process requests to the Flask's endpoint and to listen to calls from the Flask to scrapyd at the same time.

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I tried to run scrapyd as a worker process but I'm not sure how to set correct port in `scrapy.cfg` and most likely because of a wrong port I'm getting ```[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:8)```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrapyd endpoint to schedule an spider from your flask front-end which sends an http request to scrapyd and for checking if the jobs is finished you can call running jobs if job-id exist in running jobs or not . There can also be better way to do it you can return an signal after the crawling has been finished.